# Usage of cookies to notifications,

Tags: php, html, css, cookies

How can I get a div to "remove" itself after someone clicked it? forever

Like a notification, it gets removed after someone opens it. Is this even possible?

Comment: Im not sure if you are looking at PHP or javascript solution. For javascript, you probably need to use .click action using jquery then hide the div. you set a cookie variable to denote that you have remove this div. however, using cookie also mean that clearing cache the div will appear again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example using cookies.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_COOKIE['removeAd'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['removeAd'])) {
        setcookie(
            'removeAd',
            '1',
            time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
        );
    } else {
        echo '
            <div id="fancyAd">
                <span>Cheap shampoo</span>
                <form method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" name="removeAd" value="Dont show again" />
                </form>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}

?>
```

We check if the cookie `removeAd` exists, if not we display the ad as we want. And if the user press the `removeAd` button a cookie will be stored and the ad will not be shown again.

I would also like to add that this would look nicer if you send a post/get request towards a php script with javascript and then removed the ad with javascript, because then the page would not have to reload in order for the ad to disappear.

Comment: Check what @simon wrote.

Answer (score 0):

@andew larsen
If this is my notification

```
<font style="float:right">
              <nav class="dropdownContainer">
                 <span class="lightpill-n dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bell dropdown-toggle"></i> 1</span>
                   <ul class="dropdown">
                     <span class="text1">
                     Hello!
                     <p>We updated a few changes to the website. Keep yourself updated by reading more.
                       <p>
                         <span class="btn-read" style="text-align:right;">Read more</span>
                   </span>
                   </ul>
                 </nav>
                </font>
```

and I want

```
 <div class="lightpill-warn>1</div>
```

to dissapear when they open the notificaiton, how?

Comment: So when they press `Read more` you want that specific div to disappear? The div is somewere else in your code? Because I can't see `<div class="lightpill-warn">1</div>` in your code above.

Comment: <span class="lightpill-n dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bell dropdown-toggle"></i> 1</span>